# Need Help to program in python. Desperate Python newbie here :-}

Tags: python

Hy,I am newbie in python programming.I am trying to improve my programming skills.I recently joined a code learning platform called code wars for improving my coding skills. The platform is great. I am having trouble reading some code there as I am not a experienced programmer.

> Write a function that adds the digits of an integer. For example, the input receives a number: 10023. The result should be - 6 (1 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 3)

For example I found the answer that is rated higher for the above question.

```
def sum_digits_of(n:int) -> int:
return sum(map(int, str(n)))

SumDigitsOf = sum_digits_of
```

For the above solution I did not understand '(n:int) -> int' and 'map(int, str(n))'
It's not that I don't know programming but I can't understand the code like above.I know simpler methods for solving this. But how to write and understand much more efficient code. It would be great help if any of you guys suggest how will I get better or is it wise to post the code which I don't understand here [ already tried googling :) ], Cheers!

Comment: It would be wise to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]. The question "*how will I get better*" is off-topic here. And if you want to ask about the code, you need to describe which **_specific_** part of the code do you have trouble understanding.

Comment: The title "need help, don't downvote" is even worse.

Comment: Ok I uderstood will edit the question

Comment: `sum(map(int, str(n)))` break it down into each individual components. Start with `str(n)`, since `n` is `10023`, `str(n)` would give `"10023"`. [`map(func, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) applies the the `func` to each element of `iterable`. `map(int, str(n))` -> `(1, 0, 0, 2, 3)`(just for visual representation, `map` returns a generator). Now, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) adds all elements returned by the `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show “casts” an `int` to a `str`, then takes it digit by digit (`map` applies a function to something iterable, simply put), “casts” each digit back to `int` and finally `sum`s the digits. (And it is indented incorrectly.)

The final assignment merely creates an alias name for the function, it doens’t “do” anything.

In any case, strings (`str`) do not have to be necessarily involved:

```py
def sum_digits_of(n, base=10):
  result = 0
  while n:
    result += n % base
    n //= base
  return result

print(sum_digits_of(123456))
```